# Replacing strings in same text file

Tags: java, string

I am trying to replace a substring in a text file with another. When I use `replace`/`replaceAll` I see that the changes are not seen in the file.

```
temp = line.split("\"");
String str = temp[1].substring((temp[1].length())-4); 
line = line.replace(str,"rvro");
```

When I print the line before and after replacement, it's working fine but the changes are not seen in the main file

I want to use a single file for everything and write changes on it.

Comment: How does your code look like?

Comment: In general you can't just "update in place" in a file and have it work, especially if you change the length of the file in the process.  You must read/write the entire file, which it's not clear you're doing.  (Hence the need to see "all relevant code".)

Answer (score 2):

> When I print the line before and after replacement,its working fine but the changes are not seen in the main file

You need to write the string back into the file, perhaps using a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).